# angular2 ngx-cookie got reference issue

Tags: angular, cookies

I used angular2 ngx-cookie to get cookies but I got this issue...

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

and This is my constructor Inject

```
constructor(private cookie:CookieService) {
    this.cookie.get(".AspNetCore.Identity.Application");

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you getting this this error when building your project or at run time?

Comment: it's at run time...

Comment: Wild guess here, but maybe try moving your call to `this.cookie.get()` to an `ngOnInit` method. Generally speaking, you should avoid having logic that can fail in your constructor. If you have an `ngOnInit` method on your component, Angular will trigger it once your component is done initializing.

Comment: Yes!!! you are right~It works now,thanks for saving my day

Comment: Cool. I'll post a full answer below in case someone else comes across the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your constructor is called, your component is usually not done initializing. Ideally, your constructor should only be used to instantiate variables and should not include any logic that might trigger an exception.

Instead you should implement the `OnInit` interface on your component. This will cause Angular to invoke the `ngOnInit` method on your component once it has been initialized.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private cookie:CookieService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cookie.get(".AspNetCore.Identity.Application");
  }
}
```